# How To Create Chart/Graph For Windows Phone 8 Application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I would like to create a Graph something like this on a **Windows Phone 8 Application**.

[Chart/Graph http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5816/chartgraph.png](http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5816/chartgraph.png)

I'm **aware** that there are APIs and references available for WP8 but those are **paid**. I'm looking for a **free** alternative. If anyone would point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: like what ?? image link is broken

Comment: @Rinzler I've already fixed the link. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: similar question has been answered, see the following link [charts-on-windows-phone-8-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254135/charts-on-windows-phone-8-1/30481932#30481932) hope u find answer to be reasonable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following library allows you to create charts easily in Windows Phone, and it's free:

https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you point me to a doc of amCharts?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Sparrow Toolkit. It supports the next system:

- WPF
- Silverlight
- WinRT
- WP7/WP8

http://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This [repo](https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts) might work for your needs.

Comment: don't address the user, and try to formulate your response more accurately: point to a proper component/library the user can use.

Comment: The link is already shared , If u know a reasonable answer share one ,else be quite