# How to create pie charts in windows phone 8 apps?

Tags: c#, xaml

I need to create pie charts in windows phone 8. I am able to do it for windows 8 desktop but the WinRT DataVisualisation Control is not available on windows phone 8

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Create Chart/Graph For Windows Phone 8 Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645126/how-to-create-chart-graph-for-windows-phone-8-application)

Comment: @Christos I don't think it is a duplicate

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have no experience on Windows Phone 8 Applicatiobs. I found this after some googling I did. Considering the answer you gave, I think that you are more familiar with the subject. For this reason, I will retract my downvote. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the binaries are `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll` and `System.Windows.Controls.dll.` from [`Silverlight Toolkit`](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

check here : [`Create Charts & Graphs in Your Windows Phone Application`](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/wp7/article.php/c20199/How-to-Create-Charts--Graphs-in-Your-Windows-Phone-Application.htm)

Comment: i am not able to download those binaries

Comment: @TerrelLewis download the dlls from here http://www.andrearegoli.it/Blog/2013/11/14/silverlight-data-visualization-toolkit/