# Charts on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, dll, charts, libraries, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I have to draw a chart (line chart). I know there is the **WinRT XAML Toolkit** but it seems not working for WP8.1 but only for Windows 8.1 apps, like many others libraries.

There is a stable library for Windows Phone 8.1 too?

Comment: The toolkit actually works with Wp 8.1, give it a try, if it is not too late...

Answer (score 0):

Telerik's RadCharts are quite good

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/chart.aspx

Comment: Please note that this solution is not free. You should indicate it.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT XAML Toolkit is only for Apps which runs on WinRT (Store Apps).

To draw charts in Windows Phone you can use on of the following libraries:

**1. [AmCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/)**

**2. QuickCharts**

**3. [Sparrow Toolkit](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/)**

You can install them in your project through NuGet.